# IOS: Smooth launch when becoming active

Tags: ios, lifecycle

When my app has been inactive and I then click on it, initially it brings up the last screen it was on.  Then it segues to the the entry screen.

This is a bit jarring especially because the entry screen is a New screen and if nothing is New, it, in turn, segues to yet another screen.

Is there a way to better control what happens on return to active so that it  stays on the last active screen or goes straight to the entry screen without first flashing the last active screen?  I imagine this may have something to do with applicationWillEnterForeground: but with no experience with this, I find Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html) fairly dense going.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out state restoration, which is a way for you to implement a seamless transition to the last point the user left off. There are also great WWDC videos on it.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PreservingandRestoringState.html